# Android Application slows down when opening web url in phonegap's child browser

Tags: android, cordova, childbrowser

I am developing an Android phone-gap application , when i open a web url in child browser the application becomes unresponsive.is there any cache issue or anything else please help.

Comment: which version you can work ?

Comment: cordova version is 2.4.0 and checking it on Samsung DUOS 4.0.1 os version

Comment: Do you use InAppBrowser ?

Comment: No i am using childBrowser, but i have also tried inAppBrowser same problem.One more thing the url having big content as it is a blog url  which i am opening in childBrowser.